# NEO4J: Combine without union match with a WHERE ALL(x in list WHERE x in anotherlist)

Tags: neo4j

I am hoping there is a way to do this without UNION MATCH. This is part of a larger query and I'd rather not step out of it.

I have a list of n nodes and a list of x nodes. I'd like to exclude any n that's not got ONLY relationships to x nodes in xlist, but through two different relationships and one of the has a label.

```
WITH nlist, xlist
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1:Label)-[:FIRST]->(x1) WHERE n1 in nlist AND ALL (y in collect(x1) WHERE y in xlist)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)<-[:SECOND]-(x2) WHERE n2 in nlist AND ALL (z in collect(x2) WHERE z in xlist)
WITH collect (n1) + collect(n2) as n....(unwind as n)
```

this does not work because it does not like the collect x in the all.

```
WITH n, xlist,
[(n:Label)-[:FIRST]->(x1) | x1] + [(n)<-[:SECOND]-(x2) | x2] as allx
WHERE ALL (x in allx WHERE x in xlist)
WITH n ...
```

this does not work because n might not have both types of relationships and it looks like the all wants it to be both.

Grateful for any pointers.

Thanks!

----Addendum dummy input/output:

```
MERGE (n1:Label {n: 1})-[:FIRST]->(xa {x: "a"})
MERGE (n2:Label {n: 2})-[:FIRST]->(xa)
MERGE (n3:Label {n: 3})-[:FIRST]->(xa)
MERGE (n2)-[:FIRST]->(xb {x: "b"})
MERGE (n3)-[:FIRST]->(xb)
MERGE (n2)-[:FIRST]->(xa)
MERGE (n2)-[:FIRST]->(xb)
MERGE (n2)<-[:SECOND]-(xa)
MERGE (n3)<-[:SECOND]-(xc {x: "c"})
RETURN n1, n2, n3, xa, xb, xc
```

given nlist of ["n1", "n2", "n3"]:

When xlist is "a", expected result is n1

when xlist is ["a", "b"], expected result is n1, n2

when xlist is ["a", "b", "c"] or ["a", "b", "c", "d"], expected result is n1, n2 and n3

when xlist is ["d"] or ["a", "d"], expected result is null

Comment: Can you share dummy input and dummy output to get a better understanding?

Comment: Sure! I added to original post.

Comment: @Stephanie In your desired result, xlist includes the "D" node, but it is not in the initial data.

Comment: Yes - some of the items in xlist may not exist.

Comment: Imagine - you are at ice cream parlor and you only want anything that's chocolate or orange flavored (xlist), and nothing else. They only have chocolate chip or chocolate (n list). So the only one they have that suits your criteria is chocolate (because vanilla is not on your xlist). It's a little like that but with two relationships. The code I have in question works great when there's only one relationship, but not two.